# Serial Port Data Received only working when breakpoint set

Tags: vb.net, winforms, serial-port

I have a program that starts an ultrasonic wind gauge and then requests the reading after 5 seconds. When I put a breakpoint in the Data Received handler the data being returned from the wind gauge is processed correctly, however if I do not have the breakpoint in place the data is ignored. The code is as follows (startWG is called when F2 is pressed on the keyboard)

```
    Dim WGCom As New SerialPort
    Private Function initWG() As Boolean

        Dim WGPort = My.Settings.WGCom
        If Not (WGCom.IsOpen) Then
            Try
                WGCom.PortName = "COM" & WGPort
                WGCom.Parity = Parity.Even
                WGCom.DataBits = 7
                WGCom.StopBits = StopBits.One
                WGCom.Handshake = Handshake.None
                'WGCom.ReadTimeout = 3000
                WGCom.WriteTimeout = 50000
                WGCom.Open()

            Catch ex As InvalidOperationException
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)

            Catch ex As UnauthorizedAccessException
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)

            Catch ex As System.IO.IOException
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)

            End Try
        End If

        If (WGCom.IsOpen) Then
            Return True
        Else
            Return False
        End If
    End Function
#If (WGPort > 0) Then

#End If
    'What to do with the wind gauge data when it is received.
    Public Sub DataReceivedHandler(
                        sender As Object,
                        e As SerialDataReceivedEventArgs)

        Dim sp As SerialPort = CType(sender, SerialPort)
        Dim indata As String = sp.ReadExisting()
        'MsgBox("Seen Data from WG " & indata)
        If (indata.Length  0) Then
                reading = indata.Substring(plus - 1, 5)
                read = True
            End If
        Catch ex As Exception

        End Try
        Try
            minus = InStr(indata, "-")
            If (minus > 0) Then
                reading = indata.Substring(minus - 1, 5)
                read = True
            End If
        Catch ex As Exception

        End Try

        If (read) Then
            WGReading = reading
            ' MsgBox(reading)
            WGHasRead = True
            read = False
            plus = 0
            minus = 0
            Dim forClass As New WGReads
            forClass.Reading = reading
            SerialLog.WGReadings.Add(forClass)
            RaiseEvent PropertyChanged("DataReceivedHandler", New PropertyChangedEventArgs("LastWG"))
            WGFill(wgfield, hjevent)
        End If

    End Sub

    Public Sub WGStart(wg() As String, hjevents As hjCompetition)
        wgfield = wg
        hjevent = hjevents
        If (initWG()) Then
            AddHandler WGCom.DataReceived, AddressOf DataReceivedHandler

            Dim initBuffer(9) As Byte
            initBuffer(0) = &H1
            initBuffer(1) = &H13
            initBuffer(2) = &H43
            initBuffer(3) = &H57
            initBuffer(4) = &H49
            initBuffer(5) = &H2
            initBuffer(6) = &H30
            initBuffer(7) = &H35
            initBuffer(8) = &H4
            Try
                WGCom.Write(initBuffer, 0, initBuffer.Length)
            Catch ex As System.TimeoutException
            End Try
            'After init wait for the wind gauge to catch up
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100)
            Dim outputBuffer1(9) As Byte
            outputBuffer1(0) = &H1
            outputBuffer1(1) = &H13
            outputBuffer1(2) = &H43
            outputBuffer1(3) = &H57
            outputBuffer1(4) = &H53
            outputBuffer1(5) = &H2
            outputBuffer1(6) = &H30
            outputBuffer1(7) = &H30
            outputBuffer1(8) = &H4
            Try
                WGCom.Write(outputBuffer1, 0, outputBuffer1.Length)
            Catch ex As System.TimeoutException
            End Try
            'Wait for the wind gauge to finish
            wait(5500)

            'Add a handler for when data is received from the Wind Gauge
            AddHandler WGCom.DataReceived, AddressOf DataReceivedHandler

            'Get the reading from the wind gauge
            Dim getBuffer(9) As Byte
            getBuffer(0) = &H1
            getBuffer(1) = &H13
            getBuffer(2) = &H43
            getBuffer(3) = &H57
            getBuffer(4) = &H4F
            getBuffer(5) = &H2
            getBuffer(6) = &H30
            getBuffer(7) = &H30
            getBuffer(8) = &H4
            Try
                WGCom.Write(getBuffer, 0, getBuffer.Length)

            Catch ex As System.TimeoutException
            End Try
            'closeCom()

        End If
    End Sub
```

It doesn't matter where the breakpoint in the Data Received handler is but as long as there is one. If the breakpoint is in the WGStart Sub it doesn't work either.

Surely a breakpoint should not change the way the program executes?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: If you uncomment the MsgBox at the top of DataReceivedHandler does it ever appear?

Comment: On which line are you placing the breakpoint? I haven't done serial port work in a while but my guess is because the receive event is firing on first sight of data rather than when all the message has been received you're reacting too quickly/not waiting for message completion. By adding the breakpoint you're giving the buffer additional time to fill up and in turn you're seeing the whole message.

Comment: I'd report the exception messages in the two Try blocks that do nothing on exception.

Comment: Why are you using no handshaking? Does your wind gauge support hardware or software flow control?

Comment: The wind gauge is this model https://www.gillathletics.com/store/product/ultrasonic-wind-gauge There is no mention of flow control so I am guessing it is not supported.
If I uncomment the message box it appears every time, if I recomment the message box it goes back to working occasionally (the last time I tried it I got data the first two times and the nothing after that.)
It doesn't matter where I place the breakpoint, if I place it in the last section of code or the first section. Should I add in a wait(100) as a solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding in a wait(100) has fixed the issue. The code for the wait sub is as follows for others looking for a solution to similar issues

```
Private Sub wait(ByVal interval As Integer)
   Dim sw As New Stopwatch
      sw.Start()
      Do While sw.ElapsedMilliseconds < interval
      ' Allows UI to remain responsive
        Application.DoEvents()
      Loop
   sw.Stop() 
End Sub
```